# Send Failure Email From ScreenFlow

Tags: error-messages, screen-flow

I have been troubleshooting this for awhile. Not sure what I'm doing wrong. Pretty sure it's simple issue.

Below is the screen shot. I'm just trying to send an Email from a Salesforce Screen Flow when it fails. From my research, it looks like I have to do a platform event subscription in the Process Builder to get notified when a User messes up a screen. I'm not sure why this is the case.

Any suggestions?

1. Already Checked Deliverability in the Sandbox. All emails are going out.
2. Verified typos.
3. verified that the template body only contains the flow error message.

Here is the [article](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=process_troubleshoot_error_event.htm&type=5) outlining the process builder / platform event.

Here is the screen shot of my core action config:

[image: CoreActionSettings]

Comment: are we talking about sending this email on a flow fault path (from say an update records element)?  does the flow debug show this element even being executed? have you tried to see if a chatter post works instead?

Comment: @cropredy that's correct, a flow that will fire off the fault paths. The value that is failing {!Opportunity.Name} that's failing in the loop. I know how to fix this error, but wanted to make sure that if other errors occurred, the email would send. I guess it's safe to say that the fault is only in if the element fails, not if the whole flow fails.

Comment: That is correct

Comment: Very helpful. And was the correct solution. Post answer for the correct solution, and will give credit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A flow can generate a fault on a given element (for example, an Update Records element where a Validation Rule in the database triggers):

If you connect a Flow Fault connector to, say, a Core Action like Send an Email or Post to Chatter, such core action will execute.

If the Flow fails in an uncatchable way (or omitted flow fault path), [standard Flow error handling ensues](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=flow_build_logic_fault_default.htm&type=5).

[Screen flow failures publish platform events](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=process_troubleshoot_error_event.htm&type=5) that can be subscribed to (which can also then post to chatter, send email etc.)

[SFDC Doc recommends configuring a flow fault path](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=flow_build_logic_fault_email.htm&type=5) for every element that supports this.